# Xamarin on Mac with Error: /usr/bin/mono: No such file or directory

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

After setting up a Xamerin project I want to write test cases. When I run the following test case I see the app starting up on the device. Then I execute the following test:

```
    [Test]
    public void A_Show_Repl()
    {
        // Invoke the REPL so that we can explore the user interface
        app.Repl();
    }
```

One does this to explore the tree of the view in order to write further tests. However, I just see the terminal open and the following error:

```
Minhs-Air-2:~ mkn$ /usr/bin/mono "/var/folders/j4/tqn26ftj31l_xn7q71qywkt80000gn/T/uitest/repl/xut-repl.exe" android "/Users/mkn/Programming/Test/MyTest/MyTest.UITests/bin/Release/Xamarin.UITest.dll" "http://127.0.0.1:60398/" "5be7ab7369ad7e8292082a01da1506ca"
-bash: /usr/bin/mono: No such file or directory
```

It looks like that it is searching for mono in the wrong folder. I can find mono on my mac in /usr/local/bin. Is there a way to fix this in Xamarin Studio?

Comment: Looks like you have a mismatch of mono and IDE versions as newer versions of Mono now use /usr/local/bin to comply with El Capitan requirements of no /usr/bin changes. I would just create a symlink to mono from /usr/local/bin to /usr/bin for now.

Comment: Created a symlink and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading the Xamarin.UITest nuget package to latest version solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this while on a Xamarin University session - fixed with a (currently) pre-release version of Xamarin.UITest (1.1.1.257-dev).

I'm running Yosemite btw

Your mileage may vary ;-)